# Jsoup - Not able to get desired output , Help required

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, jsoup

I am new to JSOUP. Was trying a few exercise and came across a scenario where i was not able to fetch the product links from the below url.

original URL - https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/new-releases/digital-text/2275256051/ref=zg_bsnr_2275256051_pg_1?ie=UTF8&pg=1

Pasted the selected node for reference

```
<div class="zg_title">
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%83%95%E3%81%8C%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%93%E3%81%AB%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E5%92%8C%E9%A3%9F-%E7%AC%A0%E5%8E%9F-%E5%B0%86%E5%BC%98-ebook/dp/B01LYCVBW3/ref=zg_bsnr_2275256051_1 ">僕が本当に好きな和食</a>
</div>
```

my Code

```
Elements ele = doc.select("div.zg_title > a ");     
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : ele) 
{
System.out.println(element.toString()); 
}
```

Required Output

https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%83%95%E3%81%8C%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%93%E3%81%AB%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E5%92%8C%E9%A3%9F-%E7%AC%A0%E5%8E%9F-%E5%B0%86%E5%BC%98-ebook/dp/B01LYCVBW3/ref=zg_bsnr_2275256051_1

I get the correct output with xpath - `"//div[@class='zg_title']//a/@href"`
How to do this with Jsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
Elements ele = doc.select("div.zg_title > a");
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : ele) {
  System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
}
```

Things to check:

- CSS query (you have an additional space in the query);
- if you want to retrieve the `href` attribute you should use the [element.absUrl("href")](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls) method.

Comment: Thanks a ton.
Intialy i was using Xpath to solve this and was getting the below error.

Comment: {Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 

Is this because of some Sepcial JP characters.

Code-
URL urls = new URL(url);
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(urls);
Document doc = new DomSerializer(new 
CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);
  XPath BROWSE_PAGE_XPATH = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

Comment: Hi @like_to_learn if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.